# Intuition on Newton's Third Law for friction at the nanoscale

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

[image: khan academy zoomed in image of a block overcoming static friction]

This is a screenshot from a Khan Academy video on friction at the nanoscale. I understand how the force of friction on the purple block acts opposite to the direction of the force applied explained by the nanoscale diagram, but I don't understand how the Newton third law pair is explained by the diagram. Wouldn't the movement of the top layer of atoms move the bottom layer as well? In that case wouldn't the two layers move in the same direction?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no movement when we're talking about _static_ friction, and when we're talking about dynamic friction, the two surfaces won't interlock like that. The upper surface will ride up and over the "bumps" in the lower surface.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but I don't understand how the Newton third law pair is explained
> by the diagram.

It isn't.

It is not clear to me from your digram where the applied force is. But the friction force, be it static or kinetic, exerted by the surface on the block is equal and opposite to the friction force exerted by the block on the surface, per Newton's 3rd law.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a normal force (e.g. gravity), that causes the nanostructure to interlock as indicated, any horizontal force applied to the pink object will cause an equal and opposite force from the blue surface to the pink object. These forces occur at the point indicated by the yellow circles. Note that, when the box is in motion, its atoms interlock less tightly with the surface atoms, reducing the amount of friction.

In terms of your question whether the blue object should move along with the pink one:

That depends on the amount of inertia (or mass) each object presents. Assuming the blue surface is e.g. the surface of the earth and the pink object is a brick, the brick cannot move the entire earth (at least not noticably). The brick however has less inertia (mass), and can therefore quite easily be brought to a stop by the friction.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you still don't understand something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand how friction at the nanoscale works but I find applying Newton's Third Law to be more difficult for this force. For a normal force, it is quite simple to see that the third law pair would just be the opposite direction to the other normal force. However, for friction, I find it very difficult to have an intuitive sense of the third law. Could you please explain this concept to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand how friction at the nanoscale works but I find applying Newton's Third Law to be more difficult for this force.

OK, Let's say you're dragging a box over the ground

[image]

There's four different 3rd law force pairs at work here:

1. You pull the rope toward the right, and the rope pulls you *equally hard* toward the left.
2. The rope pulls the box toward the right, and the box pulls the rope equally hard toward the left.
3. The box pulls on the Earth (via dynamic friction) toward the right, and the Earth pulls the box toward the left.
4. Your foot pushes the Earth toward the left (via static friction), and the Earth pushes your foot toward the right.

If you are dragging the box at a constant velocity, then the magnitudes of all of those force pairs will be the same.

1. The Earth is at rest. Two equal and opposite force pairs are at work on it (one from dynamic friction against the box, one from static friction against your foot). The net force acting on the Earth is zero. The Earth's velocity does not change (It remains at rest.)
2. The box is sliding toward the right, Two equal and opposite force pairs are at work on it (one from friction against the Earth, one from the rope). The net force acting on the box is zero. It's velocity does not change. It continues to slide to the right.
3. You... Um, body mechanics... complicated. I'm just going to skip that bit.